# SSAS processing keeps skipping records

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, olap-cube

SSAS processing keeps skipping records although it is explicitly defined (everywhere) to convert them to unknown members:

A) in each dimension properties (Error configuration) as well as

B) in the cube properties (Error configuration) and finally

C) in the processing options (Error Configuration).
I have defined everywhere to convert to unknown member in case the key is not found however the processing keeps skipping records.

I have read in other posts the recomendations to include in the dimension a dummy record (ex. -1) to link the un-matched records. However this is not the answer to my question: Why SSAS ignores the defined properties and keeps skipping records ?

Comment: How do you know it "skips" records? SSAS normally reads all records from the data source, whether linkable or not. Is the unknown member configured to be visible in your dimensions? (`UnknownMember = Visible`, this is separate from the error configuration itself.) Have you verified the data source view isn't using a view/query with inner joins to link data to dimension values?

Comment: I know it skips because I read the processing log and it says explicitly for each record that did not find a match in the dimension that it was skipped. The unknown member is visible. I am not using a query - it is just plain reading from a fact table